# Собственное и личное мнение

Tags: синонимы

На просторах интернета попалось любопытное обсуждение. Человек задал вопрос: "Чем отличается собственное мнение от личного?" А еще больше меня заинтересовал ответ одного из пользователей: *"Собственное мнение - это то мнение, которое ты высказываешь. Т.е. тебя могут насильно заставить его высказать или навязать. Личное мнение - это то мнение, которое ты считаешь верным. Его нельзя навязать, т.к. ты думаешь именно так, а говорить можешь совсем другое"*. Другой же ответил (и я с ним согласен), что разницы между этими понятиями нет: *"Совершенно идентичный смысл у этих слов. Иное дело, что человек может заблуждаться, считая, что его собственное мнение он выстрадал сам без чьей-либо помощи и подсказки. Но на самом деле это мнение, искренне воспринимаемое самим человеком как личное, может быть сформировано пропагандой или убеждением другом или родственниками, если он критически не осмыслил его, обсудив, так сказать, с самим собой: а верно ли? А не противоречит ли некоторым фактам, о которых я достоверно знаю?"*
А как вы считаете, есть ли разница между собственным мнением и личным?

Comment: @Szael, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Личное - это чем пользуешься только ты, собственное - то, чем ты владеешь. Ср. собственные и личные вещи, собственная (которой распоряжаешься сам) и личная (частная, не для посторонних) жизнь. Поэтому, например, мысли всегда собственные, а водитель - личный.

А вот относительно мнения получается интересная штука. Человек вполне может иметь собственное мнение (личное мнение хранить невысказанным не получится), но при его высказывании оно сразу же трансформируется во мнение "личное".  Как тут не вспомнить Тютчевское "Нам не дано предугадать, как слово наше отзовется"! После васказывания мнения мы перестаем им распоряжаться, теряем над ним собственность, но делаем частью своей социальной личности.

Все вышесказанное - мое личное мнение, основанное на моем собственном мнении о русском языке.

Comment: Таким образом, мое личное мнение является моим собственным мнением....

Comment: Эти слова многозначные, поэтому надо соотнести между собой все  значения, а не  рассматривать собственность только как принадлежность. Как правило, люди  имеют личные мнения, которые они  обычно считают собственными.  Хотя эти  мнения  обычно складываются под влиянием  взглядов других людей,  условно их можно назвать таковыми, и тогда личное и собственное мнение - это синонимы.  Но бывают ситуации, когда речь(к примеру, в науке) идет об оригинальном мнении по конкретному вопросу, и тогда такое мнение следует считать только собственным.

Comment: >Но бывают ситуации, когда речь(к примеру, в науке) идет об оригинальном мнении по конкретному вопросу, и тогда такое мнение следует считать только собственным

Не бывают. В научных работах вообще не приветствуется указание на личность автора, т. к. предполагается, что читатель в ходе рассуждений приходит к такому же выводу. Учитывая, что мнение - это не более чем оценка, то возможна конструкция "по личному мнению автора", но именно личное, собственное мнение ненаучно по определению, так как не верифицируемо.

Answer (score 2):

Здесь, на мой взгляд, полная синонимия. Обратимся к словарям. 
*ЛИЧНЫЙ, - 1*
Принадлежащий данному лицу (3 зн.),
находящийся в пользовании данного лица. Л-ая собственность. Л-ое оружие. Л-ое снаряжение туриста. //
Предназначенный для обслуживания какого-л. отдельного лица, состоящий при нём. Л-ая охрана. Л. секретарь. //
**Присущий данному лицу. Л-ое мнение. Л. опыт. Л-ые недостатки.
2.**
*Затрагивающий интересы какого-л. лица (3 зн.),*
касающийся только его. ***Л-ая выгода. Л. успех. Л-ые интересы. Л-ое оскорбление. Л-ые проблемы. Моё л-ое дело***
(категорический отказ от чьей-л. помощи, выражения сочувствия и т.п.). //
*Связанный с частной, семейной жизнью, с частными, семейными отношениями данного лица.* ***Л-ая жизнь. Строить л-ое счастье.
3.***
Принадлежащий лицу (3 зн.)
как члену общества, представителю какого-л. социального слоя. Л-ые права граждан. Л-ая неприкосновенность. Л-ое дело

СОБСТВЕННЫЙ, -ая, -ое.
1.
*Принадлежащий кому-, чему-л. по праву собственности*. С-ая дача. С. автомобиль. Жить собственным домом
(самостоятельно, отдельно от родителей). //
Находящийся в индивидуальном пользовании у кого-л., являющийся личной принадлежностью кого-л. С-ое помещение. С-ая чашка. С. письменный стол. //
Находящийся в непосредственном ведении, распоряжении, подчинении кого-, чего-л. С-ая канцелярия. С. корреспондент газеты.
2.
***Относящийся лично к кому-л.; свой.*** ***С-ая жизнь. Для собственного потребления. С-ые интересы. С-ое благополучие. Чувство собственного достоинства
(=чувство самоуважения).***

Обратите внимание на второе значение слова " собственный" с его примером: (*Собственная жизнь.*) и на второе значение слова " личный" (Связанный с частной, семейной жизнью, с частными, семейными отношениями данного лица.***Л-ая жизнь***).
Вы же не будете утверждать, что личная жизнь - это чья-то жизнь еще, а собственная - принадлежащее только одному лицу. ***То же самое  с личным и собственным мнением.*** Это одно и то же.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что человек просто слегка троллил.

Answer (score 0):

Слова "личный и собственный"  часто бывают синонимами, но в ряде ситуаций для них можно отметить разные оттенки значений и разную сочетаемость с другими словами.

ЛИЧНОЕ МНЕНИЕ

1) Личное мнение - это мнение, присущее данному лицу, но не обязательно собственное (можно разделять чье-то мнение).

2) В том числе личное мнение - это мнение, противопоставленное мнению других членов общества (коллективному мнению).

СОБСТВЕННОЕ МНЕНИЕ

Собственное мнение – это оригинальное мнение, исходящее от данного лица, которое не заимствовано из каких-либо источников.

ПРИМЕРЫ:

Ну это  моё личное мнение, я не собираюсь его высказывать публично.-  Это мое собственное мнение, в учебниках этот вопрос не рассматривается.

Я много слышал об этой проблеме. Наконец, я решил всё-таки съездить и составить своё собственное мнение.

Любой учитель вам скажет: мы должны воспитать настоящих личностей, научить детей иметь собственное мнение.

Comment: >Это мое собственное мнение, в учебниках этот вопрос не рассматривается.

Интересно на каких основаниях автор декларирует собственность на данное мнение? В отличии от гипотезы, идеи, теории и т. п. оценочные суждения авторским правом не защищаются и соответственно не могут быть только его собственными.

Answer (score 0):

Отвечая на многие вопросы, я, как правило, высказываю личное мнение, основанное на личном опыте. А вот выслушивая ответы, с которыми я не согласен, могу поделиться и собственным мнением.

Answer (score 0):

Не правильно понимаете, Личное мнение на то и личное пока оно не озвучено не высказано, собственным оно становится после того как мнение озвучено, ну и общественным оно становится когда реорганизуется выразимся так, в группу единомышленников, не обязательно личное, собственное или общественное мнение должно быть достоверным, оно может быть заблуждением, Личное подразумевается приватное, собственное подразумевается индивидуальное, ну и тд. и тп.

Comment: А это где-то можно прочитать?